# Matrix (dis)allocation

Tags: c++, opencv, memory-management, shogun

I use opencv c++ API for computer vision application and I manage matrices with cv::Mat structure. Opencv use ref counting to release created object as cv::Mat.
I use also libshogun for more specific machine learning algorithms. Shogun has its own matrices structure called SGMatrix.
I initialize SGMatrix from a cv::Mat like this:

```
cv::Mat cvmat(100,100,CV_32FC1,cv::Scalar(0.0)); 
SGMatrix<float> sgmatrix((float*)cvmat.data, cvmat.rows, cvmat.cols);
```

My problem is when I use another object in shogun lib like:

```
CSimpleFeatures<float>* features = new CSimpleFeatures<float>(sgmatrix);
```

where shogun is supposed now to own the matrix created with `features`, I get an error, at runtime, when opencv try to release `cvmat` which has already been released by shogun.
How can I handle this ? I don't want to clone my matrix.

Comment: Note: I tried to add ref to cvmat object but got the same error. From shogun, not from opencv. *** glibc detected *** /home/eric/dev/(...): double free or corruption (out): 0x0000000000a2f1c0 *** ======= Backtrace: =========
/usr/local/lib/libshogun.so.12

Answer (score 3):

Shogun will de-allocate the matrix as soon as the SGMatrix and the simplefeature object are destroyed. To avoid that use

```
SGMatrix<float> sgmatrix((float*)cvmat.data, cvmat.rows, cvmat.cols, false);
```

This way you have to take care of memory deallocation!

Answer (score 2):

Allocate the memory for the inside of the matrix outside OpenCV, either with Shogun or with new / malloc. Then, create the matrix by using one of the constructors that takes as argument a `void*`pointer to the matrix data (which you have allocated before). This creates just an opencv header for your data.

That way, opencv knows it does not own the data inside the matrix, and it will not try to free it when the `cv::Mat` object is released.

Comment: Well, you have actually 2 problems (1 spurious deallocation in shogun, 1 for "how to prevent opencv from releasing my useful data"). I have the answer for problem #2, still need to find for #1... Maybe shogun is modifying the data behind your back, or erasing some opencv fields in the header, and opencv then identifies something is going wrong.